# NSURLConnection works on simulator but fails on iphone device

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

I'm testing iphone application via xCode both simulation and on iphone device. On the simulation, there is no problem, but when running on the iphone device, NSURLConnection fails, connection:didFailWithError: method called.

What can be the reason for this problem?

Comment: When didFailWithError is called, you should get an error message/code.  That would probably help you narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Find out by inspecting the NSError object that you receive in connection:didFailWithError:. See listing 3 over at the [Using NSUrlConnection documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html):

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    [connection release];
    [receivedData release];

    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSErrorFailingURLStringKey]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the problem occurs because of internet connection, error says no internet connection. I want to ask about iphone download. When the iphone is connected via cable to the mac and runs via xcode, is download be made over the mac's internet connection or iphone's connection?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I'd say it's using the iPhone's connection.

Comment: ok thanks very much, it's using iPhone's connection, because i provide  iPhone's connection and the internet connection problem is gone, but unfortunately there is time-out problem :((

Answer (score 0):

When you use the phone it is connecting through the phone's internet connection. When on the simulator it uses your computer's internet connection.

If there is a problem it is probably with the connection on the phone to whatever your connecting to. Maybe what ever your connecting to is blocking your phone? It's probably not a problem with the application if it works on the simulator.